# Update Installation Getting Failed After Target SDK Version (32 to 33) in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, mobile, google-play

My Android app developed in Java (android studio)

target version was 32

and I got a notification from the Play Store to upgrade to 33, within one year otherwise we cannot update.

so I updated it to
Target SDK Version (32 to 33) in Android Studio

but the new version is 28

and try to update on 27

the installation failed

Failed to commit install session 621146829 with command package install-commit 621146829. Error: INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Existing package com.restaurant.grilliz signatures do not match newer version; ignoring!

and it is working , if I unistall the previous and intall this new

but for my all users have old version, i cannot tell them to uninstall & update

so how to fix this

I have no idea to fix this
so please anybody help me to fix this

Comment: Share source code to reproduce your problem~